# Why is `this` equal to 0x0, causing my program to crash?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, this, smart-pointers

I'm designing a simple Connect 4 game. So far, I have 4 underlying classes:

`Colour` - responsible for representing colours (RGBA). Includes conversion operators.

`Player` - represents a player of the game. Each `Player` has a `Colour` and a name.

`Board` - represents the playing board. It contains dimensions, as well as a 2D vector of `Tile`s with those dimensions.

`Tile` - a nested class within `Board`. Represents one space on the board. Each `Tile` has a `Colour` and an `std::unique_ptr` to the owner of that tile. The owner starts as `nullptr` and can be changed **once** to a `Player`. The colour starts as a transparent black.

---

I've tested my `Colour` class and it appears to be working fine. My `Player` class is in tip-top shape as well. However, I'm having some problems with the `Board/Tile` classes.

My test consisted of creating two players, and a board. These executed normally. Next, I loop through the dimensions of the board, once for each tile. I then call

```
board.tile (j, i).claimBy (p2);
```

The loop goes through rows with `i` and columns with `j`, the way you'd expect to print it.

`tile (j, i)` retrieves the tile I'm working with. It works as expected.

---

**Chain of Events Leading to the Crash:**

`claimBy (p2)` sets the tile to become claimed by player 2. It is implemented as follows:

```
bool Board::Tile::claimBy (const Player &owner)
{
    if (!_owner)
    {
        *_owner = owner;
        _colour = owner.colour();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

`_owner` is my `std::unique_ptr<Player>`. It first checks whether the owner of the tile has been set before (i.e. is not `nullptr`). If not, it sets the `Player` inside to the one passed in. It then updates the tile's colour and returns `true`. If the tile has been previously claimed, it returns `false`.

Following the debugger, the crash occurs in the line `*_owner = owner;`. Stepping in takes me to the line `struct Player` (my declaration of the `Player` class), which I take to be the implicit copy constructor (remember the class only has a `Colour _colour` and a `std::string _name`).

Stepping in again leads me to `Colour::operator=` (which makes sense for a copy constructor to call). Here's the definition:

```
Colour &Colour::operator= (const Colour &rhs)
{
    if (*this != rhs)
    {
        _red = rhs.red();
        _green = rhs.green();
        _blue = rhs.blue();
        _alpha = rhs.alpha();
    }

    return *this;
}
```

The path turns into `*this != rhs`. This is just a reverse call to `operator==`, which is:

```
return red() == rhs.red()
    && green() == rhs.green()
    && blue() == rhs.blue()
    && alpha() == rhs.alpha();
```

The first comparison here `red() == rhs.red()` has `red()` which is just `return _red;`. This is the point at which the program crashes. The debugger states that `this` (`this->_red`) is 0x0.

I'm clueless about why this is happening. My best guess is that I'm using the smart pointer wrongly. I've never actually used one before, but it should be pretty similar to normal pointers, and I didn't think `release` would accomplish anything if the pointer is `nullptr`.

What could be the cause of `this` being 0x0?

**Edit:**
I'm sure everything is initialized, as I do so in each constructor, in member initializers (e.g. `Board::Tile::Tile() : _colour (Colours::NONE), _owner (nullptr){}`), where NONE is a transparent black.

I'm also not too proficient with a debugger, as I haven't used it that much over printing debugging values.

Comment: Side note: Does it really make sense for tiles to be boards?

Comment: @Cameron, the is-a relationship pertains to inheritance. My goal with the `Tile` class was to completely contain it in `Board`. The `tile` function was originally a `const` return, but I just changed that for testing. The tiles can be accessed from outside of `Board`, but no new tiles may be created, just worked with. Of course `Board` has non-const access through the vector of tiles (there's the has-a relationship I do provide). In short, a board object has-a 2D vector of tiles.

Comment: An unrelated comment on your design:  the game logic that manipulates the board shouldn't have to concern itself with RGBA colors.  I'd have the tile just refer to the player who controls it, and let the drawing code choose the color based on which player it is.

Comment: @chris: Yes, it's the inheritance I was questioning :-) While it may be convenient to inherit from Board, conceptually it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Wyzard, I was debating that, as `owner().colour()` is just one short step extra.

Comment: @Cameron, I have no inheritance. The board is a container for the tiles. I just contained the `Tile` class in there as all the outside needs to know is that it can manipulate tiles through a `Board` object, not that there actually is a tile class.

Comment: @chris: Oh. I haven't read your whole question ;-) I just picked up on this part: "Tile - a subclass of Board". I guess you mean a class that was defined inside the other one (inner class?), not a subclass in the usual sense of inheritance. Never mind!

Comment: @Cameron, I may have picked the wrong word floating around in my head for that. I changed it to nested class, as it should be. Sorry for the confusion :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
*_owner = owner;
```

means "make a copy of the `owner` object, and store it at the place that `_owner` points to."  The problem is that `_owner` doesn't point to anything yet; it's still null.

If you really want to make a *copy* of the `Player` object in each tile that the player controls, you'd need to do

```
_owner.reset(new Player(owner));
```

But making copies of the `Player` object is a strange thing to do.  Consider using `shared_ptr` instead — you can have both `owner` and `_owner` be `shared_ptr`s, and just assign one to the other in the usual way.

Comment: I'll look into that, thank you. I'd like the argument to be an actual `Player`, but I was thinking `unique_ptr` because it would only ever be `nullptr` or one `Player`. I guess I thought wrong.

Comment: The "unique" in `unique_ptr` doesn't mean that once you point it to a `Player` you can't make it point to a different one.  It means that when you point it to a `Player`, you're promising that nothing *else* points to that same `Player`, so it's safe to delete the `Player` when the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope.  A `shared_ptr` lets you have several pointers to the same `Player` (e.g. one in each tile that the player controls), and the `Player` won't be deleted until *all* those pointers go out of scope.

Comment: The `reset` seems to have done the trick :) I thought about it, but the fact is that each player is initialized, and has no changes made from then on. The next layer up is the "interface", which takes care of turns, wins, etc. Due to this behaviour, it is perfectly fine to make a copy and store it just for reading the player's colour, and at the same time, whether it is owned. I've read about smart pointers, so I know what the differences are, but I guess my logic behind that decision was flawed.

Comment: Making the copies won't produce wrong results (as long as you don't need to modify the `Player` afterward) but it's inefficient.  I'd recommend using `shared_ptr`s to a single `Player` object as a matter of practicing good habits, even if the current design doesn't cause significant problems right now.

Comment: That is a valid point. Although speed for claiming each tile isn't important at all, it is more scalable, and provides me with the opportunity to try out a new smart pointer.

Comment: @chris: Since you're making copies of Players, could you make a copy of me?  I could use the extra help 'round here.  More seriously, making copies of Players like this breaks the rule of least surprise in at least one way:  You can have two distinct Player objects which refer to the same Player.  So, for instance, `tile(j,i)._owner == tile(l,k)._owner` will only be true if both tiles are unowned.

Comment: @Managu, I see your point, but that comparison at least would be based on the values of `_colour` and `_name`, which would be copied over, and the originals will not change.

Comment: @chris: maybe `tile(j,i).owner() == tile(j,i).owner()`, comparing Player objects, would based on those values.  But the comparison I listed compares the underlying `std::unique_ptr<Player>`s.  That's based solely on object address.

Comment: @Managu, ah, I see what you mean. My `owner` function in `Tile` returns a `Player`. For the pointer, I have an `ownerPtr` function. I would use this as `if (_board.tile (x, y).owner() == _currentPlayer)` in my "interface" controlling the flow etc. I would have no reason to compare the actual pointers. The only reason I used a pointer over a reference was the ability to not be owned by either player yet, and it made much more sense than a dummy player, which would ruin other aspects.

Answer (score 1):

You start off with a default initialized `std::unique_ptr<Player>`.  That is to say, the equivalent of a NULL pointer with some cleanup semantics.  Then you try to dereference it in the statement `*_owner=owner;` so that you can assign to it.

Thus the statement `*_owner=owner;` is basically equivalent to `((Player*)NULL)->operator=(owner);`, calling the implicit assignment operator.  The first thing this does is then equivalent to `((Player*)NULL)->_colour=owner._colour;`  Finding `this==NULL` is not surprising here; indeed, it's expected.

The fix depends on what you actually want to happen.  Should each `Board::Tile` be given a completely new copy of its `owner`?  Then you want to instead say `_owner.reset(new Player(owner))`.  Do you just want each tile to hold a reference to an already existing player?  Can you guarantee that the Player object `owner` will outlive the Board::Tile object? Then you want a raw pointer: (in declaration of Board::Tile) `Player const *_owner;` (in implementation) `_owner=&owner;`.